# Compute determinant of large matrices - which values should use?

Tags: c++, linear-algebra, eigen, bigint, determinants

I want to make a comparison between execution time of two methods which solve linear systems: Cramer method and LU method. I use C++ 14 and Eigen. The main problem implies that Cramer method use determinants. For large matrices determinant's value become too big (eg. for 100 x 100 matrix the determinant is equal to -4.11074e+127)

What should I do? I tried with matrices that contains integer numbers from [1,9] or [-9,9], or double numbers with (2)3 decimals from [-1,1] or [-2,2] but the determinant's value is too big.

How can I deal with big numbers? OR: what values should take a large matrix (eg. 500 x 500) and then the determinant of this matrix to be a 'valid' number, (eg. 454111 instead of 2543e+45 )

Edit: to generate values from matrix I used an online random generator

Comment: I want large matrices (eg. 500 x 500) but with decent value of determinant.

Comment: Especially if you want your matrices to have a 'decent' (whatever that means) determinant you should really start with test matrices of known qualities and not randomly generated ones.  What is the probability that a random 500x500 matrix has a decent determinant ?  I don't know, but I do know that the probability of a test matrix having a decent determinant is 1 if you choose the right test matrix.  Hit your search engine.  (Using test problems with known solutions will also help you validate the accuracy of your implementations.)

Comment: How do you compute the determinants? For large matrices this is often done using an LU decomposition, so any naïve implementation of Cramer's rule will compare poorly anyways.

Comment: Note that a large random matrix has great chance to be ill-conditioned. This will cause problem in solving a linear system, whatever the method used